# Получить данные разных столбцов как один

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица, в которой храниться first_id и second_id, это айди пользователей которые между собой дружат, и мне нужно для пользователя по определенному id получить всех с кем он дружим. Его айди может находиться как в first_id так и в second_id. Я делаю вот такой запрос:
`SELECT * FROM usersLinks WHERE first_id = %1 OR second_id = %2`

Где %1 - %2 некие айди. Этим запросом я получаю всю нужную инфу, но она выглядит примерно так:

1 0

0 2

0 3

4 0

Для пользователя с id 0 я получил это. А я хотел бы получить 1 2 3 4, т.е. все нули убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можете использовать оператор `case`

```
select case first_id = 0 then second_id else first_id end as uid
from ....
```

или аналоги вида

```
select if(first_id = 0, second_id, first_id)
```

или как вариант через `union`

```
select second_id from ... where first_id = 0
union 
select first_id from ... where second_id = 0
```